# Laravel : One is to Many Relationship, get foreign key value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm currently working on **productcategories** and products *relationship*
which is *one is to many*.
I wonder why i'm having this error

> Call to undefined method stdClass::products()

Here's my model for Products

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Product extends Model
{
  public $table = "products";
  public $fillable = ['productcategory_id',
                    'name',
                    'description',
                    'price',
                    'pic',
                    'availability',
                    'featured',
          ];
  public function productcategory()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductCategory');
  }
}
```

and here's my model for Product Category

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductCategory extends Model
{
  public $table = "productcategories";
  public $fillable = ['name',
                    'description',];
  public function products(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Product','productcategory_id','id');
  }
}
```

and Here's my view file

```
@foreach($productcategories as $productcategory)
   @foreach($productcategory->products() as $product)

     {{ $product->name }}

    @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Please help me i'm getting this error all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting in the dark here, but I would first remove the parentheses in your view file from $productcategory->products().  If that doesn't solve the issue, dd($productcategories) in your Controller and verify that you're passing a Collection of ProductCategory as I wouldn't expect the resulting error to include reference to "stdClass".